# Data loss between Symfony 5 form and its Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

After looking into docs and forums without any success, I can't help but ask for some advice on why I lost data between my form and its template.

Let me explain :
I have a form with fields, that renders correctly, get their data (or empty data) correctly, except for one :
I have a ChoiceType field that gets its choices from the Database through Doctrine. At this point, everything is fine, I get my choices in a nice beautiful array as follow :

```
$choices => array:2 [▼
  "YES" => 0
  "NO" => 1
]
```

But when I add those choices in the field, and ask Twig to render it, some data is lost. And when I look into the choices that Twig renders, it looks like this :

```
 "choices" => array:2 [▼
      0 => Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\View\ChoiceView {#7158 ▼
        +label: "0"
        +value: "0"
        +data: 0
        +attr: []
        +labelTranslationParameters: []
      }
      1 => Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\View\ChoiceView {#7159 ▼
        +label: "1"
        +value: "1"
        +data: 1
        +attr: []
        +labelTranslationParameters: []
      }
    ]
```

My problem is : why do I lose my labels, while Symfony sends them as I want ?

Tell me if you need any other informations about how I create my form, how I handle it in my controller or how I render it in Twig, I'll gladly edit the post.

Please note that I am currently using Symfony 5.3.5 with PHP 8.0.9

**EDIT**

In my app, I use other forms that have the same ChoiceType field, using the same method to get the choices but the render is as expected. I compared them from the creation and data retrieve to the rendering, eveything is similar (expect few options to the field).
This is why I don't understand my trouble

Comment: If you have a solution please, don't add it inside the question, you can answer your own question adding it in the "Your Answer" section (scroll below).

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "add those choices in the field"?

Comment: By "add those choices in the field", I meant to put the array inside the field's option named "chocies" as follow

$builder->add('myFieldName', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => [
        "YES" => 0,
        "NO" => 1,
    ],
    'choice_label' => 'myLabel',
    'required' => false,
]);

But these option was overwritten by the other option named choice_label, I just had to delete the "choice_label" option and everything was as I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact I was using choice_label option coupled with choices having a label=>value was making the labels to "override" themselves and just ended up "deleting" them, defaulting the label to the value itself.
Removing the option "choice_label" from the FormType corrected everything.

Sorry for the late answer, I hadn't seen the comment posted by @gp_flower and I'll try for my next posts to answer myself if needed.